# Typescript: print keys/values of objects that contains arrays (no forEach)

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, foreach, key

i'm trying to extract values from an object that contains arrays.
Here's how the object look like:

```
export const myBookList: Row[] =
[
    {
        bookInfo: [
            {
                title: "The jungle book",   
                isbn: "42398486965239671234",
                Author: "Rudyard Kipling"
            },
            {
                title: "20,000 Leagues Under the Sea",
                isbn: "42234486234239675678",
                Author: "Jules Verne"
            },
            {
                title: "The Call of the Wild",
                isbn: "4239848696523967670",
                Author: "Jack London"
            }
        ],
        value: [],
        id: 0
    },
    {
        bookInfo: [
            {
                title: "The jungle book 2",   
                isbn: "327865923874659276",
                Author: "Rudyard Kipling"
            },
            {
                title: "20,000 Leagues Under the Sea 2",
                isbn: "269587649587264675",
                Author: "Jules Verne"
            },
            {
                title: "The Call of the Wild",
                isbn: "2378687827584758765",
                Author: "Rudyard Kipling"
            }
        ],
        value: [],
        id: 1
    }
];
```

I would like to go through all the keys and values of the object (especially the keys/values in the array bookInfo) and when a key that match the passed string parameter "myKey" is found, i would like to return the key value.
The code below works ok, but since the entries on myBookList are more than one... when i found i match i can't exit the procedure due to the for each iteration (forEach in typescript doesn't accept break or return) and i get always the last entries of the object.
How to solve this?

```
getValue(data: Row, myKey: string): string {
let retValue: string = "";
data.forEach(function(item) {
    item.bookInfo.forEach(function(key, index){
        console.log(key, index);
        if (key===myKey) {
            console.log(key, index);
            ret=key.value;
        }

     });
});
return retValue;
```

}

Comment: `.filter()`, `.find()`, `.findIndex()`, a simple `for` loop, ... (which are all mentioned as alternatives in the notes section of the [`.forEach()` documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` loop. When you meet condition, then we can use `return` statement to get the desired values:

```
const getValue = (data, myKey) => {
  let i = 0;

  while (data.length > i) {
      let bookInfoIndex = data[i].bookInfo
                                 .findIndex(f => Object.keys(f).includes(myKey));
      if (bookInfoIndex != -1)
        return data[i].bookInfo[bookInfoIndex][myKey];

      i++;
  }
}
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [{bookInfo: [{title: "The jungle book",isbn: "42398486965239671234",Author: "Rudyard Kipling"}, {title: "20,000 Leagues Under the Sea",isbn: "42234486234239675678",Author: "Jules Verne"      },{title: "The Call of the Wild",isbn: "4239848696523967670",Author: "Jack London"}],  value: [],    id: 0  },
  { bookInfo: [{title: "The jungle book 2",isbn: "327865923874659276",Author: "Rudyard Kipling" },   {title: "20,000 Leagues Under the Sea 2",isbn: "269587649587264675",Author: "Jules Verne"}, {title: "The Call of the Wild",isbn: "2378687827584758765",Author: "Rudyard Kipling"}], value: [], id: 1 }];

const getValue = (data, myKey) => {
  let i = 0;

  while (data.length > i) {
      let bookInfoIndex = data[i].bookInfo.findIndex(f => Object.keys(f).includes(myKey));
      if (bookInfoIndex != -1)
        return data[i].bookInfo[bookInfoIndex][myKey];

      i++;
  }
}

console.log(getValue(arr, 'title'));
```